# Get JSON response in Python, but in original JavaScript format

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am putting a JSON response into a variable via `requests.json()` like this:

```
response = requests.get(some_url, params=some_params).json()
```

This however converts JSON's original `"` to Python's `'`, `true` to `True`, `null` to `None`.

This poses a problem when trying to save the response as text and the convert it back to JSON - sure, I can use `.replace()` for all conversions mentioned above, but even once I do that, I get other funny json decoder errors.

Is there any way in Python to get JSON response and keep original JavaScript format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`json()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) is the JSON ***decoder*** method. You are looking at a Python object, that is why it looks like Python.

Other formats are listed on the same page, starting from [Response Content](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content)

- `.text`: text - it has no separate link/paragraph, it is right under "Response Content"
- [`.content`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content): binary, as bytes
- [`.json()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content): decoded JSON, as Python object
- [`.raw`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content): streamed bytes (so you can get parts of content as it comes)

You need `.text` for getting text, including JSON data.

Comment: Another option would be serializing the object again. That would ensure it is valid and they all have the samef formatting. That means they wouldn't be saved verbatim though. Depends on use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the raw text of your response with `requests.get(some_url, params=some_params).text`

It is the `json` method which converts to a Python friendly format.